# Objective-C error message while creating NSRange

Tags: objective-c, nsrange

I try to create an NSRange object in Objective-C on my Mac. Unfortunately it gives me an error message which I cannot solve or debug.

```
NSRange newRange = [data rangeOfData:dataToFind
                                      options:kNilOptions
                                        range:NSMakeRange(0u, [newData length])];
```

The error message I get is:

```
*** -[NSConcreteData rangeOfData:options:range:]: range {0, 81701012} exceeds data length 347124
```

The size of dataToFind is : 57854
The size of newData is : 81701012

The max. size of the NSRange length is by default an NSUInteger : 18446744073709551615

so what is the error message about? Where do the 347124 come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are searching in `data` yet you provide the range to search starting from zero of the length `newData.length`. Apparently `newData` is longer than `data`. Change to `NSMakeRange(0u, [data length])`.

Answer (score 2):

You are referencing `data` but using the length of `newData`:

```
NSRange newRange = [data rangeOfData:dataToFind
                                      options:kNilOptions
                                        range:NSMakeRange(0u, [newData length])];
```

That doesn't look right.